# Do I need to run campaign to get payment?

Tags: admob

I'm new to AdMob so I want to clarify whether I need to add a campaign for my app that's live in Google Play Store (with ads) in order to get payment from AdMob?

Also explain me about the AdMob campaigns. Do I need to pay AdMob to someone else when I reach my goal in a campaign? Like to other publishers?

Thanks,
Kvaibhav01.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to AdMob so I want to clarify whether I need to add a campaign for my app that's live in Google Play Store (with ads) in order to get payment from AdMob?

->**You don't need to create campaign to get payment from Admob for apps. You will receive payment from Admob once threshold limit is crossed.**

Also explain me about the AdMob campaigns. Do I need to pay AdMob to someone else when I reach my goal in a campaign? Like to other publishers?

**->** Campaigns are for companies who want to publish ads, if you are app developer you are displaying these ads in your app.
Refer this links for further information

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6162747?hl=en

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6231370?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: I've one more query: How does AdMob calculates the _Threshold Amount_ ? (Which is in the Payments tab.) Estimated earnings plays some role in this?

Comment: How google calculates it? Not sure but it's same for everyone i think..

Comment: Hi @AmodGokhale currently AdSense says my estimated earning for this month is $1.47 (I recently setup my AdMob.) But when I go to the _Payments_ tab in AdMob or AdSense it says _You've reached 0% of your payment threshold_ even when I've earned a dollar! It should've shown me that I've reached 1% of threshold...Why?